# What % can be regarded as "normal" "not viewed traffic" reported in AWStats?

Tags: web-crawlers, spam, web-traffic, awstats

Recently statistics for my site is about 50% "not viewed traffic". This seems much as many robots are blocked. What % of "not viewed traffic" can be regarded as "normal"?

Is my site under attack when 50% of traffic is generated not by normal users using their browsers?

What can be done to reduce "not viewed traffic" (I am using nginx server)?

Comment: [Half the web's traffic comes from bots](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3070022/internet/half-the-webs-traffic-comes-from-bots-and-thats-costing-you-more-than-you-think.html)

Comment: OK, one question left - what can be done to forbid several known and unknown bots?

Comment: I am not a AWStats fan. When I was a web host, AWStats was a natural to offer my users, however, I found that the information poorly structured and confusing. Instead, I used SawMill to create meaningful information. Today, I suggest Piwik. It is free and excellent. Likely one of the very best.

Comment: As for bots, there are two popular options; Fail2Ban and ModSecurity. Both are effective, however, you may want to review how to use each to see which one is best for you. Otherwise, the task is far too great and requires constant attention. Cheers!!

Comment: @ closetnoc, thanks for reply, I am using f2b, iptables to block attackers (mainly from china). Could you post an answer so we have some info which can be voted (both - info on AWStats and about bots). Thanks.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to block all bots from your site?  Google's web crawler, for example, is a bot, and if you block bots such as it, you may find it adversely affects your site's indexing in search engines.  Then where is your traffic going to come from?

Comment: @FKEinternet, no Google, Bing, Yahoo and some other bots blocking. BUT there are THOUSAND's of bots, some very malicious and aggressive !!! Do you have a website?

Comment: "This seems much as many robots are blocked." - Just because you are _blocking_ many bots doesn't necessarily mean they are not still hitting your server and being logged (and hence reported on by AWStats)? If you are implying otherwise? Unless of course you are already blocking these bots with a front-end server/proxy/firewall _before_ it even gets to your application server?

Comment: @DocRoot, you are right, I am blocking some bots in nginx configuration, so AWStats sees the hits from nginx server logs. Do you suggest moving blocking from nginx server to firewall?

Comment: @snayob Yes, I have many web sites (I own about 1700 domain names).  I don't know what you mean by "no Google, Bing, Yahoo and some other bots blocking"  I use `sshguard` on my FreeBSD system to intercept malicious traffic at the firewall, the internal servers (Apache, etc.) never see most of the attacks I think you are referring to.

Comment: @FKInternet, I did'nt know you have so much experience on websites. I mean "I do not block Google, Bing, Yahoo and a few other well known bots", but I want to block all other bots. Thanks for info on sshguard.

Comment: "Do you suggest moving blocking from nginx server to firewall?" - Well, that should keep the bots out of your application servers log (and AWStats report). But you only _need_ to do that if these bots are actually causing a problem for your application server. Otherwise, it's just a statistic in your AWStats report. And if you split the logs, you now have two logs to check?

Comment: What's the tracking for? Have you considered a client side report? The problem with blocking bots without a fully managed service is that eventually you'll block real people. Especially where vpns, proxies and other network nodes come into play. Not to mention the 'good 'bots.